# How to hide included merge layout - Kotlin null exception

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I need to hide the visibility of my layout but because it's an included layout with the merge tag I'm not being able to do it. I'm using kotlin and keep getting a null pointer exception when trying to hide the view by using

```
layout_bookings_past.visibility = View.GONE
```

with this import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_bookings_past.*
```

but tried also with

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_bookings.*
```

That's my code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<include
    android:id="@+id/layout_bookings_past"
    layout="@layout/layout_bookings_past" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for the merge layout I have something like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <merge xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Thanks very much.

Ps: I've a sample app that simulates the structure of my project [here](https://github.com/francislainy/samplemergelayout)

Comment: What's the import line of `layout_bookings_past`?

Comment: Hi @mol. Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I forgot to paste the import. It's updated now.

Comment: Try to replace it with: `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.parent_layout_name.layout_bookings_past`

Comment: Tried this now ```import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_bookings.layout_bookings_past``` but still got the null error exception unfortunately

Comment: Does direct lookup `rootView.findById(R.id.layout_bookings_past)` work?

Comment: Not really. Tried now.

Comment: Created a sample app that simulates the structure of my project in case that helps? https://github.com/francislainy/samplemergelayout

Comment: Is it crucial for you to use `<merge>` tag? When you use it, all it's children are merged into parent layout, so `layout_bookings_past` doesn't exists. You can use any `ViewGroup` instead of merge, or change visibility of each child individually.

Comment: Thanks @mol. Not crucial no and I know I can change each view individually but because it would mean over 10 changes and then changing them back again when the button is pressed I posted this question here trying to check if there's a way to avoid doing that by just controlling the parent merge layout. But thanks very much for your help anyways. Appreciate your time looking into it with me.

Comment: No problem. Please check out my answer with additional details and another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks @mol. Too bad it doesn't seem to be possible to do it just using the merge layout but I appreciate you looking into the issue for me and have accepted your answer now. Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `<merge>` tag, merged views are actually merged right into parent `ConstraintLayout`, so `ViewGroup` with id `layout_bookings_past` doesn't exist.

To make sure you can check your layout in `Layout Inspector`:
[image]

You can notice, that `tv_past` and `rv_past` are childs of `ConstraintLayout` that is root layout of `FragmentBookings`.

The solution would be to add actual `ViewGroup` instead of `<merge>` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_past"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Past bookings"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_buttons" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_past"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_past"
        tools:itemCount="2"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

There's another option, if we assume, that we always include this layout to `ConstraintLayout`. You can add `android.support.constraint.Group` ([more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group)) as a child of `<merge>` and reference it in your code. Like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/merged_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv_past,rv_past"/>
```

And just reference it as usually:

```
merged_layout.visibility = View.GONE
```

But I guess it is just easier to add `ConstraintLayout` as parent of the layout. Getting rid of redundant layouts is good, but not worth it in that case.